# How to Implement MSFileReader to open Thermo Raw files using C++

Tags: c++

I have been asked to use MSFileReader from Thermo Fisher to read RAW files and do some peak picking for mass spectrometry data. I can load the DLL included in the package, but cannot access the functions. I have version 3.0. I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 as my compiler. My code is below.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

double SampleWt;
double *pd = &SampleWt;
typedef std::string(*MYPROC)(int);

int main()
{
    MYPROC ProcAdd;
    HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Nathan\\DanforthPrj\\MZmine- 2.16\\lib\\vendor_lib\\thermo\\MSFileReaderLib.dll");
    if (!hinstLib)
    {
        std::cout << "\ncould Not Load the Library" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "\nSuccess" << std::endl;
    }
    ProcAdd = (MYPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "Open");
    if (NULL != ProcAdd)
    {
        std::cout << "\nfinaly" << std::endl;
    }
    //Resolve the function address 6
    FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Using a similar process, I can use other DLL files. What could be going wrong? I don't receive any error messages. The name of the function I am tryng to load is simply "Open".

Comment: Are you sure that's not a COM library?

Comment: "MSFileReader is ... designed to be used with C++-based applications, but since it is a COM object, you can use any language that supports the COM interface."